# Extruder motor not running

Tags: extrusion, motor

I have run into an issue in which my extruder motor isn't running on my Voxelab Aquila. This issue just came up yesterday when I started a print and noticed that while the X and Y axes were moving just fine and it was going through the motions, absolutely no filament was coming out. I could manually push filament through to the hot end so I ruled out a clog, and after canceling the print, I pulled the filament back a bit and told it to auto-load, which it failed to do - the filament did not move at all.

Initially, I thought maybe the motor had died on me, but after swapping the X and Extruder plugs, I found the motor itself is running just fine. After that, I figured maybe it was just the cable itself, but I've swapped the extruder cable for the X cable and it's moving the X-axis motor as if nothing is wrong.

I have not been noticing unusual errors in my prints, so I believe this is a sudden problem - in fact, I just completed a successful series of prints last week that took around 20 hours total. The only thing that I think may have been an indicator of trouble is a smell somewhat similar to a hair dryer that got extremely strong yesterday before I decided to test the motor. I know I have read complaints in the past about the mainboard in the Aquila, could this be a problem there?